# How to clear flutter desktop app data like flutter mobile app

Tags: database, flutter, dart, caching

I'm working on a flutter desktop app, and I want to clear the app database. Like as we do on mobile, we go to app settings and clear cache and data, to reset the app settings. Likewise, how can I do the same with a desktop app?

Comment: Since this is a feature of your operating system and most desktop operating systems don't have that feature, I doubt there will be an easy explanation. How are you saving the data you want cleared?

Comment: I'm using sqflite_common_ffi plugin for local database in desktop app. I want to clear that database and rebuild it.

Comment: Just delete the file?

Comment: Did try flutter clean, but not working

Comment: No, the database file. How do you open your database?

Comment: How can i access database file for flutter desktop app?

Comment: Well, how do you access other files? Using your file explorer. Can you post the code on how you open your database?

Comment: Desktop is three different OSes, each of which stores user data in a different place. You should clarify which platform you are taking about because the answers will be different.

Comment: Any success? How to clear data in Windows?

Comment: At the time creation of database for the first time we allocate it some path, I found path from there and then manually delete the file from that path. Flutter clean only clear the build files not database file.

Comment: Does anyone found path to the cache for Windows desktop app build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
 return LazyDatabase(
    () async {
      var dbFolderPath = '';
      if (GetPlatform.isDesktop) {
        final provider = PathProviderWindows();
        dbFolderPath = (await provider.getApplicationSupportPath())!;
      } else {
        final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        dbFolderPath = dbFolder.path;
      }

      final file = File(path.join(dbFolderPath, _databaseName));
      debugPrint(file.path);
      return NativeDatabase(file);
    },
  );
```

Just print the path of your database and you will know exactly where it is stored. For me, it's stored in this path:

flutter: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\PACKAGE_NAME\debt_record\db.sqlite

Comment: I found my shared preferences and database in the path C:\Users\khadi\AppData\Roaming\{you application} and able to clear app preferences and databases if any.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this in Linux by deleting the flutter_app_directory found in
~/.local/share/<flutter_app_name>

Similar actions can be found in Windows and macOS.

Comment: need a path for MAcOS

Comment: or `~/Library/Containers/<flutter_app_name>` for macos

Answer (score 4):

My issue was related to Hive on Windows, and I managed to solve it with the following solution (I think it works on other platforms as well):

```
 await Hive.initFlutter();

 var appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
 print(appDir);
```

Also don't forget to import the path provider as follow:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

You will get something like this on the debug console

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents
```

When you navigate to that directory, you will find the files you need. For Hive, I found all the boxes files like `box_name.hive` and `box_name.lock`, so I deleted the files related to my issue and that resolved it.

This would work with all the other storage packages as well.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, I had to open [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) and then hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and paste this:

> `~/Library/Application Support`

And in the app package folder, I found all the files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need today, on [macOS v13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura). I had conflicts on a [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database schema and even with Flutter clean it didn't disappeared. Only was was to delete the previous *.sqlite* file (*of course, this only works in early stage of your app development, stay retro-compatible with your previous database schemas as soon as you have real users with device installs*).

### Find the path to the database

```
sudo find / -name {my_database_name}.sqlite
```

This gave me the following result:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/{my_username}/Library/Containers/{full_qualified_app_name}/Data/Documents/{my_database_name}.sqlite
```

Example:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/gerfaut/Library/Containers/com.example.todoapp/Data/Documents/tasks.sqlite
```

### Delete the SQLite file

- with [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)): Hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, paste the path to the file, and manually delete it
- or with [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal): `rm /System/Volumes/Data/Users/{my_username}/Library/Containers/{full_qualified_app_name}/Data/Documents/{my_database_name}.sqlite`

Relaunch your Flutter app and a new database is created!

Comment: What do you mean by *"Only was was"*? Removing a "was" does not make it any better. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74937161/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).